# How does this sed command work?

Tags: sed

I need to print text between two text fragments. I've found such example, that does exactly what I want, but I don't understand how it's done. Googling is difficult because command does not contain letters)

`sed -n   '/hostname/,/$/p' /tmp/ambari-agent.ini`

hostname=localhost

As I understand, here I print text between `hostname` and line end. `p` option prints pattern to output. But why do I have three groups here and what does coma mean here?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242469/bash-sed-grep-text-between-two-words

Comment: Thank you, Zoredache.
I've found the complete doc here http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost always the first place you should look is the [man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed).  They are often difficult to read, but the information is there.

From the man page `p  Print the current pattern space.`, it is in the subsection `Commands which accept address ranges`.  Which would easily lead you to the idea that you are specifying a start and end address range by using regular expressions, see the `Addresses` section.  So `/hostname/` is the start and `/$/` is the end.  The `$` is a special character that marks the end of a line.